# How to launch Chrome using Selenium WebDriver synchronously with createSession()?

Tags: typescript, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code that launches a Chrome browser using Selenium WebDriver:

```
import { Driver } from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';

Driver.createSession();
console.log("I've launched!");
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that I'd like to print "I've launched" AFTER the browser has actually successfully launched. However, what I'm seeing is that "I've launched" gets printed to the console BEFORE the Chrome instance actually gets launched.

How can I launch Chrome synchronously using `createSession()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a very reliable method of waiting for the browser to be launched is to wait for the session to resolve. Therefore, the full code becomes:

```
import { Session } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { Driver } from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';

(async function example() {
    let driver: Driver = Driver.createSession();

    // Wait for the browser to be launched
    let session: Session = await driver.getSession();

    console.log("I've launched!");
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to invoke a WebDriver wait on something simple like the page title.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.title_contains("expectedTitleOfBrowser"))
```

This will wait until the title of the browser is "expectedTitleOfBrowser", which usually requires the browser to fully start before the wait is completed.

If you are just starting the Chrome session, and not actually navigating anywhere, the title will be something generic like `data;` or `Untitled`.